# Why is this route not updating anything in my database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I believe there's an issue with the syntax on the filter. I'm not sure what the right way is to access the object by id but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. It could be something entirely different but this is what I'm guessing because it seems that all the other info is passing correctly but the filter skips the object I want to update. I don't get any error messages and everything seems to work perfectly, however nothing ever gets updated in my object.

Here's the code (I'm sorry if I did this wrong, this is my first post here.):

```
router.post("/update", async (req,res) => {
    const apartment = await ApartmentsModel.findById(req.body._id);
    const id = req.body._id;
    let comments = req.body.comments;

    try {

        console.log(comments);
        const response = await apartment.updateOne(
            { "_id": ObjectId(id)},
            { $set: { comments: comments } }
          );
        res.json(response);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json(err)
    }
});
```

I've changed the syntax around a bit but nothing seems to be working.

Value of req.body.comments:

```
[ 'hello, test comment.' ]
```

Value of const apartment:

```
apartment {
  _id: new ObjectId("648f2e7447f84e869ac481c2"),
  address: '330 Ophelia St',
  description: 'Decent sized apartment with nice views.',
  imageUrl: 'https://images.rentable.co/5452/65863545/large.webp',
  rating: '4',
  comments: [],
  userOwner: new ObjectId("64795a13c254bdb60a1ed286"),
  __v: 0
}
```

Comment: What is the response from the database?

Comment: The response seems to just be "{}" empty curly  brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just have a couple of small errors. The main issue is the line where you're searching for the matching `_id` with `ObjectId(id)` - you only need to pass in the `id` itself, not an `ObjectId` object. This should work:

```js
router.post("/update", async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const response = await ApartmentsModel.updateOne(
            { "_id": req.body._id },
            { $set: { comments: req.body.comments } }
          );
        res.json(response);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json(err)
    }
});
```

Edit: [It's recommended to use `save()` instead of `updateOne()`](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/update):

```js
router.post("/update", async (req,res) => {
    const apartment = await ApartmentsModel.findById(req.body._id);
    try {
        apartment.comments = req.body.comments || apartment.comments;
        const response = await apartment.save();
        res.json(response);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json(err)
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've made the change and its getting further but for some reason its still not working. This is the response I get now: response {
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}

Comment: It is interesting that the matchedCount is 1 but the modifiedCount is 0. Can you confirm that `req.body.comments` is different from what's already stored as `comments` in the collection?

Comment: Yes, comments in the collection is an empty array. I actually realized I had a few things different than your answer so I changed them but now I'm back to getting no response. I also noticed the console logs I have after the updateOne function don't ever get read.

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to include the value of `req.body.comments` and the result of console.logging the `apartment` const from your original post? It would be helpful to see how the record is structured and what type of data you're adding.

Comment: Sure thing, I've added those values to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: Thanks. This one has me scratching my head, that looks like it should work to me and I have nearly identical code in my own projects that works. I edited my response to include one more thing you can try.